# import a dump file mysql ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql server on my machine running ubuntu then after installation I did the following:

1. mysql -u root -p   to get mysql prompt
   2.create database prediction ;
2. create user adam;
3. set password for adam = password("12211");
4. grant all privileges on prediction.* to adam identified by '12211';
5. use prediction;
6. -u adam -p prediction

I get the error :

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u khalil -p prediction

Answer (score 0):

Your error message doesn't correspond to your #6 entry (`adam` v.s. `khalil`). In any case, you cannot simply enter `-u whatever` into the mysql command line. Those are command line options, not sql commands/queries. You'd need to EXIT mysql first, then re-enter

```
$ mysql -u adam -p prediction
```

at the shell prompt