# mysql import dump file ubuntu 10.10

Tags: mysql

am running mysql server on my machine using ubuntu, am trying to import dump file as indicated below, I get an error shown below as well:

```
create database mm;
create user rami;
set password for rami = password("112211");
grant all privileges on prediction.* to rami identified by '112211';
use prediction;
-u rami -p mm </home/user/Downloads/SNPdbe_2012_03_05_sql;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u rami -p mm

Comment: It tells you in the error what the problem is: `-u rami -p mm` is not a valid SQL statement ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [import a dumb file mysql ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337938/import-a-dumb-file-mysql-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4):

While in the `mysql>` prompt, use the `source` command to import the file.

```
mysql> create database mm;
mysql> create user rami;
mysql> set password for rami = password("112211");
mysql> grant all privileges on prediction.* to rami identified by '112211';
mysql> use prediction;
mysql> source /home/user/Downloads/SNPdbe_2012_03_05_sql;
```

Otherwise, from the shell prompt in Linux, run it from the command line as you attempted to do inside MySQL:

```
$ mysql -u rami -p mm </home/user/Downloads/SNPdbe_2012_03_05_sql;
```

This should then prompt for your password and import the file into the database `mm`.  It is unclear from your command attempts if you wanted to import this into the database `mm` or into `prediction`. If it should have been `prediction`, use:

```
$ mysql -u rami -p prediction </home/user/Downloads/SNPdbe_2012_03_05_sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mysql -u rami -p prediction < /home/user/Downloads/SNPdbe_2012_03_05_sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Install pv (PipeViewer)

```
sudo apt-get install pv
```

pv displays progress of your data import (percentage), elapsed time and predicts remaining time

```
pv /home/user/Downloads/SNPdbe_2012_03_05_sql | mysql -u rami -p prediction
```